Linux, mp3info. Найти на флешке mp3 файлы, из тегов составить список вида исполнитель - песня - расположение файла
find media/name/usb_flash -type f -name '*mp3' -exec mp3info -p"%t - %a\n" {} \; > /home/name/mp3_list.txt

Нашел такой код, выводит песня - исполнитель (то, что вначале название песни, устраивает), надо бы еще местоположение добавить к каждому файлу.

find media/name/usb_flash -type f -iname '*.mp3' -exec mp3info -p"%t - %a -- %F\n" {} \;

а чтобы вывод был красивым:
find media/name/usb_flash -type f -iname '*.mp3' -exec mp3info -p"%t;%a;%F\n" {} \; | column --table -s';' --table-columns ПЕСНЯ,ИСПОЛНИТЕЛЬ,ПУТЬ --table-truncate ПУТЬ


спасиб, 1ый вариант рабочий, направил вывод в текстовой файл.  xed открывать не хочет, ошибки в потоке. Geany открыл.  Второй вариант в консоли выдает по кол-ву файлов строку "find: ‘mp3info’ завершен по сигналу 13"

@eugene
xed открывать не хочет, ошибки в потоке -- странно, установил себе xed, полученный файл открывает без проблем, да и с чего бы иначе, это простой текстовый файл. Второй вариант в консоли выдает по кол-ву файлов строку "find: ‘mp3info’ завершен по сигналу 13" -- а вы полностью команду скопировали ? просто если вы в последнем ключе --table-truncate забыли указать колонку то как раз и будет выводить вышеуказанную вами ошибку.
п.с. ключ --table-truncate обрезает указанную колонку до размера терминала, если вам нужно для файла то данный ключ можно упустить.
